# How change to administrator account from standard account

Tags: user-accounts, administrator, user-groups, standard-user

I have a computer with 3 different accounts. All the accounts are administrators except mine. How do I change my account to a administrator account.I can't log on to the 2 other accounts and I don't want to touch any thing with those accounts. Even if I can't actually change the account I need to have administrator privileges.

Comment: Ask the person who owns one the adminstrator accounts ...

Comment: If you don't have access to an administrator account this cannot be done

Comment: It would hardly be a secure system if a standard user could promote themselves ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first of all, this is a super sketch question. Please don't take my answer and

1. Get yourself fired
2. Get yourself arrested
3. Get yourself put on a no-fly-list
4. Get yourself grounded
5. Get me fired
6. Get me arrested
7. Get me put on a no fly list

and that's not just a "don't get caught". Don't do anything you shouldn't be doing.
I'm just answering this on the off chance it's a laptop you just bought and don't have the password to or some BS. At the end of the day if you're browsing a forum to figure out how to get admin on a system you shouldn't, the IT person who you'd be subverting is probably good enough to catch you and punish you accordingly.

There's no perfect way to do this because Windows actually does have security in place (duh), but that being said how I would do it is (assuming unencrypted hard disk)

1. Boot to Ubuntu Live CD/USB
2. Take out any networking (whether that's Wifi or unplugging the network cable) 
   God forbid there's a chance this is setting alarms anywhere
3. Mount the host hard drive
4. Go to C:\Windows\System32
5. Rename (in linux you'd use the mv command) sethc.exe to whatever you want
6. Copy cmd.exe to sethc.exe
7. Reboot into windows
8. Hit shift five times
9. You now have a system command prompt, net user username /add to make a new user and net localgroup Administrators username /add to add that user as admin
10. If you care about the environment at all, move sethc.exe back and remove the command prompt sethc.exe

**This is also for local users. Not domain.**
Someone please let me know if this is off bounds but I've actually used this to recover lost passwords for laptops in an IT environment.

Answer (score 0):

- Activate in-built Admin account by typing this onto Command Prompt

> net user administrator /active:yes

- Logout and login using Admin account
- Go to **Control Panel**> **User Accounts**> **Manage another account**.
- Select the Standard Account.
- Select Admin and press **Change Account Type** to confirm and save.

Answer (score -2):

After I did some research, I found this solution.

- First live boot ubuntu
- Next install chntpw
- Then open up your `Windows\system32\config` folder
- Now open terminal and type "cd /media/path to your config folder"
- Enter `sudo chntpw -u Lincoln SAM` (Lincoln is the username for the standard windows account)
- Once the User Edit Menu come up hit 3 and enter.

  [image]

That's it. For more info please refer to

- http://www.pcworld.com/article/206809/admin_no_password.html
- http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

The first link is for deleting a administrator password so when you get to the User Edit Menu push 3 instead of 1.

Comment: Why are we not providing the full details in the answer itself?

Comment: Is it the full details but if your having problems, refer to the links

Comment: That isn't how answers work here at Superuser.  All relevant information should be self-contained in the answer itself, and links only be used as external sources and/or additional supplemental information.  The existing information isn't detailed enough.

Comment: You said (in the question) "I don't want to touch any thing with those [other] accounts [which are administrators]".  Doesn't the above solution clear (erase) Lincoln's password?  Not only is that extremely obvious tampering (Lincoln might, quite justifiably, take the PC to IT for quarantine and forensic analysis), it is also potentially destructive — if Lincoln has encrypted files, this might destroy his ability to access them.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to superuser. If there's  anything I missed feel free to edit the post. No I don't think it erases the password just promoted the standerd user

Comment: @jo900 superuser is often like this - your sincere contribution often isn't appreciated. there's nothing you can do.